# C++: Is there a way to extract type out of instanced template?

Tags: c++, templates

```
//a class template to do something to STL container
template<typename T/*should be a STL container*/,typename Ele/*the type of element*/>
struct foo{
T a_container_with_an_element(){
    T con;
    Ele e;
    con.push_back(++++e);
    return con;
}
```

As you can see, it's really foolish to put the element's type into templates' parameter because it's already contained in the container's type.

So, is there any magic to get the element's type out of T?

Lots of Thx :-)

Comment: It depends how you want to use it. For example, you can use `typeid(...)` if you want to use the type as a key in a container, or `typeid(...).name()` if you'd like it as an std:string.

Comment: Do you mean something like `typedef typename T::value_type type`?

Comment: I really just wouldn't recommend `++++e`.

Comment: @Niall That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your special case where you know that T is a STL container Naill's  answer is correct, use the nested types in the container.

If however you want a more generic "I know I am getting a template as T and I want the type of the first parameter of that template" case you can get the type through template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyFirstElement;
template<template<typename...> class T_Container, typename T_Type, typename... Ts>
struct MyFirstElement<T_Container<T_Type,Ts...>>{
    using Type = T_Type;
};

//unit test
using MustBeInt = typename MyFirstElement<std::vector<int>>::Type;
using MustBeLong = typename MyFirstElement<std::map<long,float>>::Type;

static_assert(std::is_same<MustBeInt,int>::value,"");
static_assert(std::is_same<MustBeLong,long>::value,""); 

//this works too even though its not an STL container
template<typename T, typename U, typename Z>
struct MyCrazyContainer{};

static_assert(std::is_same<typename MyFirstElement<MyCrazyContainer<bool,long,float>>::Type,bool>::value,"");
```

here is a live example: http://ideone.com/OxhSOc

As Jarod42 pointed out this will only work with templates which are "regular" i.e. only have types as parameters. std::array for example breatks this because it has an int as a second parameter.

Comment: It is not so generic... It doesn't work for container as `std::array`. You may try something like `std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin(std::declval<Container>()))>::type`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes it is, as any approach is, limmited. As I stated its not really an answer to the OPs question but it does answer a question that undoubtedly many would expect under the OPs question title.

Answer (score 5):

If the container is a standard library container, the name of the element is an embedded name of the container as follows:

```
typedef typename T::value_type type;
```

The standard container's have a few standard names in them (for example, see [vector on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) and the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) §23.2.

```
X::value_type
X::reference
X::const_reference
X::iterator
X::const_iterator
X::difference_type
X::size_type
```

Answer (score 3):

Every "*container*" in the standard library, tries to adhere to the [`Container` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container). This concepts requires that, given a container `T`:

1. `T::value_type` is the type of the container element
2. `T::reference` is a reference type to the container element
3. `T::const_reference` is a constant reference type to the container element

In your specific example, you can extract the element type by:

```
template<typename Container>
struct foo {
Container a_container_with_an_element(){
    Container con;
    typename Container::value_type e;
    con.push_back(++++e);
    return con;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `T` should be an STL container you could use a template-template parameter. It must be a container that supports `push_back()` and we will incorporate the fact that STL containers contain a 2nd "allocator" parameter.

In that case you can use

```
template< template<typename, typename> class Con,  
          typename Ele, typename Alloc = std::allocator<Ele> >
struct foo
{
  typedef Con<Ele, Alloc> container_type;
  typedef Ele value_type;

  container_type a_container_with_an_element()
  {
    container_type con;
    value_type e;
    con.push_back( e ); // or modify e first but not ++++e
    return con;
  }
};
```

Your code would then do

```
foo< std::vector, int > myfoo;
std::vector<int> myvec = myfoo.a_container_with_an_element();
```

If you want just one template parameter

```
template< typename Con >
struct foo
{
  typedef typename Con::value_type value_type;
  Con a_container_with_an_element()
  {
    Con con;
    value_type e;
    con.push_back( e ); // or modify e first but not ++++e
    return con;
  }
};
```

and usage:

```
 foo<std::vector<int> > myfoo;
 std::vector<int> myvec = myfoo.a_container_with_an_element();
```

Note that in this example you can also do `foo<std::vector<int> >::Ele` to get the element type. You could make a `typedef` for the container type too. Often used in templates. (You need `typename` when the template is not fully qualified. So `foo<std::vector<int>>` is fully qualified and doesn't need it there.

Comment: The template template parameters will not work. All `std` containers have at least 2 template parameters - element type and allocator. Not to mention the fact that `Ele` should probably not be template template parameter anyway.

Comment: The allocator is always optional so I would have expected it to work. I did type it wrong though for Ele. I will have to check later if my solution compiles.